# Why is my area calculation coming out as 0.00?

Tags: qgis, area, qgis-2.10

I have a polygon layer where I am unable to calculate the areas for some reason, and it gives me the result 0.00 for all of the polygons. I have another layer on the same project where this works fine. Any ideas what might be causing this?

[image: screen shot of zero areas]

[image: screen shot of fields]

Comment: Most likely linked to the coordinate system you are using. Are you using something like WGS84 (EPSG:4326)? If so, you should use a metric coordinate system, such as UTM.

Comment: It is in WGS84, but when I change it to OSGB the result is the same.

Comment: Just looked it up and that one is in degrees too. You should try something like UTM Zone 30 N, EPSG:32630. Then run your area calculation again.

Comment: I have another layer in this project which is in OSGB and the areas calculate fine (I don't know how I've come to have mixed coordinate systems, but I don't think it's related)

Comment: Are you sure the resulting numbers are correct? 'ponds' sounds like a rather small area, which might return 0.0 whereas a larger area might return 'actual' numbers, but still no useful areas.

Comment: Did you add the field with the field calculator?

Comment: I've tried adding another feature on this layer, and made it nice and big. Still the same result. When I created the feature it showed the area as NULL, and when I ran the field calculator it changed to 0.00

Answer (score 1):

Your table field must be set to "Double " to calculate areas. http://www.gislounge.com/calculating-polygon-area-in-arcmap/

Did you try to add a new feature and calculate the area for that? Yes, Typ is double and typename is real.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using QGIS not ArcMap though. The field type is "Real" which I think is the same as "Double". It's not giving me an error, but seems to be doing the calculation and giving a 0.00 value. I think if nothing was happening it would say NULL

Comment: "Real" is often *single* precision (32-bit float); you should check further.

Comment: Check also for geometry validation. I think if geometry coordinates is for example wrong oriented would output 0.00

Comment: I've checked that and no errors found

Comment: you have only two decimals to store the area calculation,  if you increase the number of decimals allowed in the calculation it will show something other than 0.00

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in latlon format (i.e. projection is geographic) then it will give such result. save the data in a projected coordinate system and then it will give out the area.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old post but i passed 2 hours to find by myself so maybe someone will have the same problem !

Check in project properties, unities set in the measure parameters. For me, it was already set to Hectare so when i wrote my formula round($area)/10000, all my polygons showed 0.00 or 0.01 ha ... ^^!

I hope it'll help you